# Как пронумеровать строки в angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день. Есть следующий код. Я хочу пронумеровать список.

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js" ng-app>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.js"></script>
   ...
<script>
        var Voprosi= function($scope){
            $scope.VoprosiDB ={
            year:"2014 новые",
            ekzamen:"Крок-1",
            vopros:[
                    {id:"543",disciplina:"Математика",Vopros:"Cколько будет 2+2",Varianti:[{id:"8765",variant:"Наверное 1",isTrue:"false"},{id:"8761",variant:"Наверное 2",isTrue:"false"},{id:"8769",variant:"Наверное 4",isTrue:"true"}]},
                    {id:"5438",disciplina:"Химия",Vopros:"Cколько будет 2+2?",Varianti:[{id:"8765",variant:"Наверное 1",isTrue:"false"},{id:"8761",variant:"Наверное 2",isTrue:"true"},{id:"87611",variant:"Наверное 4",isTrue:"false"}]}
        ] 
            };
        };
    </script>

        <div id="ContentDiv" ng-controller="Voprosi">
        <div id="LeftBar" >
            <table id="TableVoprosov" >
               <tr ng-repeat="vopr in VoprosiDB.vopros">
                    <td>
                        <div class="NomerSpiska">{{1+x}}</div> //как мне пронумировать список
                        <div class="NazvanieDisciplini" >{{vopr.disciplina}}</div>
                        <div class="IdVoprosa">id{{vopr.id}}</div>  
                    </td>
                </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте переменную $index внутри ng-repeat.

Comment: Нигде ненадо. Просто пишите {{ $index }}